# Delete first 5 rows of each worksheet in a workbook if they contain no values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete all the first 5 rows of each worksheet if they do not contain any values across all columns. This program will run but only on the active worksheet. Is there something I missed?

```
Sub DeleteFirst5Rows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    Rows("1:5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
 Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, my workbook contains many worksheets. I thought this loop would go through each worksheet but it only affects the active one.

Comment: `If Application.CountA(ws.Range("1:5") = 0 Then ws.Range("1:5").EntireRow.Delete` - delete rows

Comment: What if there is a single value in the fourth row but no values in rows 1, 2, 3 and 5?

Comment: It shouldn't delete it if it contains values in rows 1 to 5, as it checks that whole range. I would test it if you are unsure but it seemed to work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated code, worked perfectly. Thank you all.

```
Sub DeleteFirst5Rows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Application.CountA(ws.Range("1:5")) = 0 Then ws.Range("1:5").EntireRow.Delete

    Next ws
End Sub
```